# read system call error (bad file descriptor)

Tags: c, unix

I am having this code in which I am getting BAD FILE DESCRIPTOR problem at the read system call. However my write call with the same file descriptor is working fine. Please suggest

```
    void Update_Log( )
{
        struct logDetails update,update1[30];
        struct stat fileData,fileData1;
        int file;
        int index;
        //pthread_t pid;
        char writeBuffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
        char readBuffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
        char mBuf[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE],mBuf1[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
        if((access("/home/team02/DMS/Server/",F_OK))==0) //checking the file/dir existence
                puts("file found");
        else
                puts("file not found");
        if((file=open("/home/team02/DMS/Server/filename.txt",O_RDONLY|O_WRONLY|O_APPEND,S_IRWXU))==-1)
                perror("file not opened");
        if((fstat(file, &fileData))==-1)
                perror("structure not filled");
        if((stat("/home/team02/DMS/Server/f1",&fileData1))==-1)
                perror("structure not filled");

        //printf("%d/n",fileData.st_mtime);
        //printf("%d",fileData.st_ctime);
        struct tm *mytm = localtime(&fileData.st_mtime);
        struct tm *mytime=localtime(&fileData1.st_mtime);
        strftime(mBuf1,18,"%I:%M:%S-%m%d%y",mytime);
        strftime(mBuf, 18, "%I:%M:%S-%m/%d/%y", mytm);
        puts(mBuf);
        if((strcmp(mBuf,mBuf1)==0))
                puts("equal");
                                else
                puts("not equal");
        strcpy(update.timestamp,mBuf);
        strcpy(update.clientName,mBuf);
        strcpy(update.filename,mBuf1);
        snprintf(writeBuffer,MAX_BUFFER_SIZE,"%s %s %s",update.clientName,update.filename,update.timestamp);
        //printf("%s",writeBuffer);
        //if((pthread_create(&pid,&thread_handler,NULL))!=0)
                //perror("Thread not created");
        if((write(file,writeBuffer,strlen(writeBuffer)))==-1)
                perror("write unsuccessful");
        **if((read(file,readBuffer,MAX_BUFFER_SIZE))==-1)
                perror("read unsuccessful");**
        for(index=0;index<strlen(readBuffer);index++)
        {
                sscanf(readBuffer,"%s %s %s",update1[index].clientName,update1[index].filename,update1[index].timestamp);
                printf("%s",update1[index].clientName);
        }
        close(file);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `O_RDWR` instead of `O_RDONLY|O_WRONLY`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the run time library, the open mode `O_RDONLY|O_WRONLY` may be problematic.  You probably want `O_RDWR` to replace that part.

<s>Also, you can get the `errno` value to find out exactly what the problem is.</s>  You are calling `perror()` in the case of an error.  That should be telling you what the issue is.  What output does the program generate?

Comment: @aviral - so what was the problem?  How did you "get it working"?

Comment: but I am not getting anything in readBuffer..any suggestions?

Comment: @paulsm4 i changed the flags as wallyk specified.

Comment: @aviral:  The open mode is append, so the write appends at end of file.  What do you expect it to read at that point?  It is positioned at end of file.

Comment: it was setting the EBADF :bad file descriptor